# How do you put information under moved div/image that is moved with translate/top?

Tags: html, css

Here is an example of what I mean:

```css
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  top: -50px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.flabber.nl/sites/default/files/archive/files/i-should-buy-a-boat.jpg">
<p>
  testing to see when it will work
</p>
```

The text is supposed to be right under the image, but I still want to move the image/div up.

I also want to move the text without top/translate, cause I will have to move all the text/div's/images that will come under that.

Comment: When you was adding that jsFiddle link to your question... you must have seen the alert. That alert does not means that you should wrap your *link* into `code`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below:

```
top:0px; 
margin-top:-50px;
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1fu1y4nw/

Answer (score 0):

the `<p>` tag has a margin by default, you just need to remove the margin.

try try this:

```
img {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```